# Connect PC_A(with a private IP) to PC_B(with a private IP) using/through PC_C(with a public IP) using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line, windows, configuration

Basically

I have a client running in a **PC_A** (PC_A is connected in a LAN hence having a **private IP**)

I have a server running in a **PC_B** (PC_B is connected in a LAN hence having a **private IP**)

==> I want to make a connection between **PC_A** and **PC_B**, which I  cannot directly since they have private IPs.

I thought of using tunneling through **SSH using a third PC_C**, with a known **public IP**, to act as a bridge or a relay to connect both of them under TCP.

Would you please **explain the setup** of SSH and the command lines I should run in each machine please?

By the way, I am using Windows platforms.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It should be asked on _Super User, Server Fault _ and similar. This section is about _Unix and Linux_ .

Comment: What are private IP for you? Because two hosts with private IP (in their official meaning, like `192.168.37.65`) can certainly communicate among them. Also, by definition, all hosts are connected in a (W)LAN.

Comment: Usually folks will use some kind of a VPN to pull this off. There are VPN appliances which will make this dead easy if you don't want to roll your own. (Assuming that the LANs are not in the same location).

Comment: What I mean here is that PC_A is connected in a company's network. Lets call the 1st network of company A LAN_A

& the other host, PC_B, is connected in another company's network. Lets call the 2nd network  of company B LAN_B
meaning that they r in different LANs. The issue is that all the machines in each company have private IPs yes, but all of them connected to the external world through one single public IP. So, trying to access one PC from another using IPs wont work especially that both companies use firewalls.

Comment: I thought of using SSH tunneling to by pass the firewalls using a third public machine to act as a relay and use SSH for that. 

Any inquiries please?

Answer (score 0):

You need a third server that is reachable by ssh from PC_A and that in turn can reach PC_B; let's call it PC_G (for Gateway).

In your $HOME/.ssh/config on PC_A put this:

```
Host PC_B
  ProxyCommand ssh PC_G nc -w 120 PC_B 22
```

Now, if you execute `ssh PC_B` on PC_A, ssh looks up the config for PC_B, and sees that the specified proxy command has to be run. So it runs `ssh PC_G nc -w 120 PC_B 22` which starts the command `nc -w 120 PC_B 22` on PC_G. This is the `netcat` command, opening a connection to PC_B port 22 (the ssh port). Now the local ssh can connect via this tunnel to the ssh client on PC_B.